# Disable selecting holidays from datapicker in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to customize the datepicker calendar so that it could have a bindableproperty to hold a list of holidays which should be disabled in the datepicker. It will need a custom renderer, but i don't know exactly the required code to implement this in iOS and Android projects? Any help is much appreciated